# Ionic iOS Push Notification When app suspended

Tags: ios, push-notification

```
`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` can be called and can get the notification details. With notification details, there is a URL that needs to be opened in the in-app browser. We tried our self to open the InAppBrowser in the `AppDelegate` but, can't be achieved. Is there any alternative workaround to achieve this?
```

To achieve the goal, I need to customize the cordova plugin but I am very new to Objective C. 
From the alert body i could get the URL string . Now, I need open/initiate the cordova plugin "InAppBrowser" from Objective C which can't be achieved. I have tried the below after importing In-App browser plugin but no luck

Code:
    NSMutableDictionary *userInfo =

```
[launchOptionsbjectForKey:
UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]; 
if (userInfo.count>=1) {

NSDictionary *apsInfo1 = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]; 
NSDictionary *alertData = [apsInfo1 objectForKey:@"alert"]; 
NSString *alertDataBody = [alertData objectForKey:@"body"]; 

}
I have tried the below after importing  but no luck. How to open the cordova plugin features from Objective C? .
```

Thanks

Jawaharlal

Comment: You should show your code

Comment: @Paulw11 Question edited .